# Changing the text colour in the Appbar without changing the text colour in rest of app

Tags: android, android-theme

I would like to set the text color in my app bar to white and leave the text in the rest of my application as the default black colour.

Setting the `android:textColorPrimary` to white make the app bar text to white, but also make the text in drop downs and calendar dialog fragments white.

How do I make the text in the app bar white, without changing the colour of the text in drop downs and calendar dialog fragments?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to manually add a Toolbar to your activity and have a TextView inside of it-

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="App Title"
            android:textColor="@colors/colorBlack"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

You might also need to set the parent theme to

> Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to make default text color white in app bar:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        ...
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/CustomTextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTextAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

    ...

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your styles.xml add :

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- Customize color of navigation drawer icon and back arrow -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
</style>
```

Then in your layout file add custom toolbar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/anyId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:title="Yor title here"
        app:titleTextColor="#fff"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```